# Problems with innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have issues with innerHTML in my code. It seems not to recognise the HTML tags and prints the data only.

Here is the line

```
document.querySelector('#listreceipts').innerHTML = '<tr><td>' + grower + '</td><td>' + receipt + '</td><td>' + amnt + '</td><td>' + pdate + '</td></tr>';
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: It would help to see your markup as well...

Comment: And the contents of your variables

Comment: Is `listreceipts` set as id attribute/selector of any of your sibling in your page ?

Comment: @rahulmr that's not the problem here...

Comment: if `#listreceipts` is not one of `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`, then it is invalid to place `<tr>` in it and will be removed by the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **#listreceipts** is `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` it should work:

```js
var grower = 1;
var receipt = 2;
var amnt = 3;
var pdate = 4;

document.querySelector('#listreceipts').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + grower + '</td><td>' + receipt + '</td><td>' + amnt + '</td><td>' + pdate + '</td></tr>';
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="listreceipts">

</table>
```

So you need to add `+=` instead of `=`. If **innnedHTML** code parsed well by browser it will work;

Comment: But that's just pure speculation and thus not really an answer to the question, because the question is not answerable in its current state.

Comment: worked! now just formatting. was using a div not a table